# Create an asynchronous function with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function that retrieve asynchronously a password from the keychain.

In MyStaticClass

```
static getPassword() {
      Keychain
      .getGenericPassword()
      .then(function(credentials) {
        console.log('Credentials successfully loaded for user ' + credentials.username);
        return credentials.password
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Keychain couldn\'t be accessed! Maybe no value set?', error);
      });
      }
```

I tried to call the function and receive the promise with this code but the result is undefined

```
MyStaticClass.getPassword().then((data) => {
      alert(data);
      });
```

I also tried this code and password was also undefined

```
static async login(){
const password = await MyStaticClass.getPassword();
alert(password);
}
```

Comment: What does it log? And can you log: `console.log(JSON.stringify(credentials,undefined,2))`?

Comment: Your `getPassword` function could simply be `return Keychain.getGenericPassword()`.

Comment: I change it to retun('test') in getPassword(), it still dosen't work

Comment: You have to return the promise in `getPassword` >> `function getPassword() { return Keychain... }`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing return statement in getPassword method

```
return Keychain ...
```